# How to use a Type variable in a generic method call (C#)

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Type variable `t` passed into a method, and I want to use it as a generic parameter when calling `IQueryable.Join` like the following

```
queryResult.Join<Type1, Type2, t, Type3>( items, outerSelector, innerSelector, ( a, b) => a);
```

It obviously doesn't work. What should I do to `t` in order to achieve what I intended? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you've got to call the method with reflection:

- Get the generic method template with `Type.GetMethod`
- Call [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) passing in your 4 type parameters
- Invoke the method passing in the regular arguments

It's a pain :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the details of your "type variable," but if the variable is already a generic parameter to the method, you can use it as a generic parameter to Join also:

```
public void MyMethod<T>()
{
    // do some stuff to get queryResult, then
    queryResult.Join<Type1, Type2, T, Type3>(items, outerSelector, innerSelector, (a, b) => something);
}
```

Comment: I see I've been Skeeted here, but I'll point out too that, in my example, T must be determinable at compile time.  Carry on.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. In this case, T can't be determined at compile time.. :(

Comment: Are you sure?  Well, OK, yes, you're sure, but sometimes there is a way to refactor so that T is determinable at compile time.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Absolutely, that's always nicer.. The thing is that I tried to refactor this monster this whole day without any luck, so I think I need to fall back..