# How can I get the MethodInfo of Queryable.Join

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, iqueryable

This may sound stupid but I cannot get the `MethodInfo` of `Queryable.Join(...)`. I want to get it because of [How to use a Type variable in a generic method call (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760848/how-to-use-a-type-variable-in-a-generic-method-call-c)

It has 2 available method signatures and I want to get the one without IEqualityComparer, so I need to specify `Type[]` in `GetMethod`.

I wrote something like

```
MethodInfo joinMethod = typeof( Queryable ).GetMethod( "Join", new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>), typeof(Expression<Func<>>), typeof(Expression<Func<>>), typeof(Expression<Func<>>)});
```

but it doesn't work. I'm unable to specify the types in generics above, because they are passed as `Type` from outside (and this is why I need this reflection).

Can anyone tell me how? Thanks!

Comment: Remember that `Queryable.Join` is an extension method so the first parameter of the method is `this IQueryable<TOuter>`. Additionally, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269578/get-a-generic-method-without-using-getmethods) question is very similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working with generics and reflection can be a bit tedious. Your best bet (to keep things simple) is to use `GetMethods` and filter by what you are looking for.

```
//Overly simplified
MethodInfo joinMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(m => m.Name == "Join" && m.GetParameters().Length == 5)
            .First();
```

Given that, the `MethodInfo` is not invokable at this point. You need to make a generic version of it by using `joinMethod.MakeGenericMethod(/*type array*/)`. In your case, you would need to use 4 types: TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult.

```
var genericJoinMethod = joinMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[]{your types here});
```

Now you can use `genericJoinMethod` as you'd expect to.

As far as I know, that is the only way to do it if you don't know the types at compile-time.

**EDIT**:

Given your comment, I think it should look something like this:

```
MethodInfo joinMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(m => m.Name == "Join" && m.GetParameters().Length == 5)
            .First();
var genericJoinMethod = joinMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TType), typeof(TType), JoinKeyType, typeof(TType));
result = genericJoinMethod.Invoke( result, new object[] { result, items, OuterKeySelector, InnerKeySelector, ResultSelector } );
```

Comment: That really simplifies things! I got another error when trying to invoke the method after making generic method like this `joinMethod.MakeGenericMethod( typeof( TType ), typeof( TType ), JoinKeyType, typeof( TType ) );
    result = joinMethod.Invoke( result, new object[] { result, items, OuterKeySelector, InnerKeySelector, ResultSelector } );` The error is "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true".. Any ideas?

Comment: @uni - Make sure you use the new `MethodInfo` that `MakeGenericMethod` returns when calling `Invoke`.

Comment: I'm wondering if somewhere in the DLR there isn't all of this already, the C# part must have something to resolve the `MethodInfo` from call in a specific call site. But it might not be exposed :(

Answer (score 1):

Before you start to implement some complicated reflection search with strings and parameter counts involved, why don't you step back, and let the compiler do what he is better at?

```
var fakeExp = (Expression<Func<IQueryable<int>>>)(() => new int[0].AsQueryable().Join(new int[0], x => x, x => x, (x, y) => x));
return ((MethodCallExpression)fakeExp.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

Obviously you can put whatever you want in your expression, as long as the top level stuff is your Join method call. Types do not matter neither.