# Using a Type Variable in a Generic

Tags: swift, generics

I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760848/how-to-use-a-type-variable-in-a-generic-method-call-c) except for Swift. How do I use a `Type` variable in a generic?

I tried this:

```
func intType() -> Int.Type {
    return Int.self
}

func test() {
    var t = self.intType()
    var arr = Array<t>() // Error: "'t' is not a type". Uh... yeah, it is.
}
```

This didn't work either:

```
var arr = Array<t.Type>() // Error: "'t' is not a type"
var arr = Array<t.self>() // Swift doesn't seem to even understand this syntax at all.
```

Is there a way to do this? I get the feeling that Swift just doesn't support it and is giving me somewhat ambiguous error messages.

**Edit**: Here's a more complex example where the problem can't be circumvented using a generic function header. Of course it doesn't make sense, but I have a sensible use for this kind of functionality somewhere in my code and would rather post a clean example instead of my actual code:

```
func someTypes() -> [Any.Type] {
    var ret = [Any.Type]()
    for (var i = 0; i<rand()%10; i++) {
        if (rand()%2 == 0){ ret.append(Int.self) }
        else {ret.append(String.self) }
    }
    return ret
}

func test() {
    var ts = self.someTypes()

    for t in ts {
        var arr = Array<t>()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Swift's [static typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages) means the type of a variable must be known at compile time.

In the context of a generic function `func foo<T>() { ... }`, **T** looks like a variable, but its type is actually known at compile time based on where the function is *called from*. The behavior of `Array<T>()` depends on `T`, but this information *is* known at compile time.

When using protocols, Swift employs **dynamic dispatch**, so you can write `Array<MyProtocol>()`, and the array simply stores references to things which implement `MyProtocol` — so when you get something out of the array, you have access to all functions/variables/typealiases required by `MyProtocol`.

But if `t` is actually a *variable* of kind `Any.Type`, `Array<t>()` is meaningless since its type is actually not known at compile time. (Since `Array` is a generic struct, the compiler needs know which type to use as the generic parameter, but this is not possible.)

I would recommend watching some videos from WWDC this year:

- [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=408)
- [Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=414)

I found this slide particularly helpful for understanding protocols and dynamic dispatch:

[image]

Comment: Mmm, so this is the heart of the problem. I guess I should watch those videos then!

Answer (score 7):

There is a way and it's called generics. You could do something like that.

```
class func foo() {
    test(Int.self)
}

class func test<T>(t: T.Type) {
    var arr = Array<T>()
}
```

You will need to hint the compiler at the type you want to specialize the function with, one way or another. Another way is with return param (discarded in that case):

```
class func foo() {
    let _:Int = test()
}

class func test<T>() -> T {
    var arr = Array<T>()
}
```

And using generics on a class (or struct) you don't need the extra param:

```
class Whatever<T> {
    var array = [T]() // another way to init the array.
}

let we = Whatever<Int>()
```

Comment: This would fix my example, but it doesn't work in general. What if you have a variable-size array of types you want to pass in? I actually have that, but I wanted to post a simple example. I'll add an example where generics won't work.

Comment: Still a good answer though. This is helpful in the case that I know enough during compile-time. But I'm receiving types over a network connection and trying to build objects from them, so I'm looking for the totally general solution.

Answer (score 5):

jtbandes' answer - that you can't use your current approach because Swift is statically typed - is correct.

However, if you're willing to create a whitelist of allowable types in your array, for example in an `enum`, you can dynamically initialize different types at runtime.

First, create an `enum` of allowable types:

```
enum Types {
    case Int
    case String
}
```

Create an `Example` class. Implement your `someTypes()` function to use these enum values. (You could easily transform a JSON array of strings into an array of this enum.)

```
class Example {
    func someTypes() -> [Types] {
        var ret = [Types]()
        for _ in 1...rand()%10 {
            if (rand()%2 == 0){ ret.append(.Int) }
            else {ret.append(.String) }
        }
        return ret
    }
```

Now implement your test function, using `switch` to scope `arr` for each allowable type:

```
    func test() {
        let types = self.someTypes()

        for type in types {
            switch type {
            case .Int:
                var arr = [Int]()
                arr += [4]

            case .String:
                var arr = [String]()
                arr += ["hi"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you may know, you could alternatively declare `arr` as `[Any]` to mix types (the "heterogenous" case in jtbandes' answer):

```
var arr = [Any]()

for type in types {
    switch type {
    case .Int:
        arr += [4]

    case .String:
        arr += ["hi"]
    }
}

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would break it down with the things you already learned from the first answer. I took the liberty to refactor some code. Here it is:

```
func someTypes<T>(t: T.Type) -> [Any.Type] {
    var ret = [Any.Type]()
    for _ in 0..<rand()%10 {
        if (rand()%2 == 0){ ret.append(T.self) }
        else {
            ret.append(String.self)
        }
    }
    return ret
}


func makeArray<T>(t: T) -> [T] {
    return [T]()
}

func test() {
    let ts = someTypes(Int.self)
    for t in ts {
        print(t)
    }
}
```

This is somewhat working but I believe the way of doing this is very unorthodox. Could you use reflection (mirroring) instead?

Comment: This is interesting and creative, but I don't think it is usable. Say you add `var arr = makeArray(t)` in `test()`'s `for` loop. `arr` will be of type `Array<protocol<>.Type>`, which can't be cast to anything.

Comment: Strangely, this fails whenever I try to put anything dynamic in there instead of `Int.self`. Like this: `var type:Any.Type ;
        if (rand()%2 == 0){ type = Int.self } ;
        else { type = String.self } ;
        let ts = someTypes(type);`

Comment: And I don't like the error messages I'm getting for this. It's like Swift is making up the rules as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible so long as you can provide "a hint" to the compiler about the type of... `T`.  So in the example below one must use `: String?`.

```
func cast<T>(_ value: Any) -> T? {
    return value as? T
}

let inputValue: Any = "this is a test"
let casted: String? = cast(inputValue) 
print(casted) // Optional("this is a test")
print(type(of: casted)) // Optional<String>
```

Why Swift doesn't just allow us to `let casted = cast<String>(inputValue)` I'll never know.

---

One annoying scenerio is when your func has no return value.  Then its not always  straightford to provide the necessary "hint".  Lets look at this example...

```
func asyncCast<T>(_ value: Any, completion: (T?) -> Void) {
    completion(value as? T)
}
```

The following client code DOES NOT COMPILE. It gives a "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" error.

```
let inputValue: Any = "this is a test"
asyncCast(inputValue) { casted in
    print(casted) 
    print(type(of: casted))
}
```

But you *can* solve this by providing a "hint" to compiler as follows:

```
asyncCast(inputValue) { (casted: String?) in
    print(casted) // Optional("this is a test")
    print(type(of: casted)) // Optional<String>
}
```