# As operator in Swift

Tags: swift

What does the `as` operator expect as a right hand side argument?

and why wouldn't it accept a `ClassName.self` or `variableName.dynamicType`?

My question comes down to the difference between `.self`, `.dynamicType` and a *real* class name?

Comment: This is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905060/using-a-type-variable-in-a-generic/30905722#30905722); perhaps you will find an answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as` operator expect a *static* Type as the right hand argument. Here the word *static* means something known to the compiler at compile time.

Both `.self` and `.dynamicType` are **expression**s, and therefore are not expected by `as` operator. Expressions are evaluated at runtime. In the case of `.self` and `.dynamicType`, they return a Type after evaluation.

Anyway, `as` operator does not expect something to be evaluated to be its right hand argument, but a "hard-coded" Type. This feature allows Swift to enforce compile time checking.

Hope this makes sense.