# Array from AnyClass or dynamicType, Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to achieve this in Swift 2.1

```
class Apple
{
}

class Fruit
{
    let apples = [Apple]();
}

let fruit = Fruit();

let appleType: AnyClass = Apple.self;
let applesType: Any = fruit.apples.self.dynamicType;

let properties = Mirror(reflecting: fruit).children;
for property in properties
{
    let magicalApples = property.value;

    let array = Array<appleType>(); // creating array of Apple from type

    let apples = magicalApples as! Array<appleType> // typecasting to array of Apple from type
    let moreApples = magicalApples as! applesType // typecasting to [Apple] from type
    let anyApples = magicalApples as! Array<AnyObject> // error SIGABRT, is this a bug?
}
```

Commented objectives throws error, "Use of undeclared type".

**My objective is to know if `appleType`, type stored in a `var`, can be used as a `Type`**

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve with this?

Comment: for now, so I can do `apples.append(appleType.init())` or `moreApples.append(appleType.init())`

Comment: You should probably be looking at using protocols

Comment: Read this answer to understand why this is not possible in Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30905722/4572536

Comment: thanks @DevAndArtist this explains everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works to append `apples` to `magicalApples`.

```
// Edit: NSObject added
class baseApple: NSObject
{
    required override init()
    {

    }
}

class Apple: baseApple
{

}

// Edit: NSObject added
class Fruit: NSObject
{
    var apples: [Apple] = [Apple]();
}

let fruit = Fruit();

let appleType: baseApple.Type = Apple.self;

let properties = Mirror(reflecting: fruit).children;
for property in properties
{
    let magicalApples = property.value
    var apples = magicalApples as! NSArray as Array<AnyObject> // first typecast to NSArray
    apples.append(appleType.init()) // apples are now edible
    // Edit
    fruit.setValue(apples, forKey: "apples"); // apples supplied, of course I am assuming fruit object will be obtained dynamically.
}

fruit.apples.count; // output: 1
```

Above works for this situation.
Although, the answer is 'it's not possible with Swift 2.1'

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905722/4572536) explains it, thanks @DevAndArtist for the link.

Comment: Even if this code does compile, the bridged `magicalApples` remains empty ;)

Comment: @DevAndArtist not anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't assign a new type, because it's a let.
`Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'ClassName.Type'`

-- Update --

`let anyApples = magicalApples as! Array<AnyObject>` should be
`let anyApples = magicalApples as! Array<Any>`?

-- Update 2 --

Look at the [references](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

Comment: I don't want to assign, I want to typecast.

Comment: You sad "My objective is to know if appleType, type stored in a var, can be used as a Type".. However now I'm editing the answer.

Comment: exactly, "can be used as a **Type** for *typecasting*". Anyways your code gives error, refer to my answer.