# Protocol conformance not recognized in generic function

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I would appreciate any insight on this issue I'm having. I'm trying to create a generic function in Swift that accepts any type that conforms to a specific protocol. However, when I pass a conforming type into this method, I get a compiler error saying the class doesn't conform.

Here's my protocol:

```
protocol SettableTitle {
    static func objectWithTitle(title: String)
}
```

And here's a class I've made that conforms to this protocol:

```
class Foo: SettableTitle {
    static func objectWithTitle(title: String) {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Finally, here's my generic function that lives in a different class:

```
class SomeClass {
    static func dynamicMethod<T: SettableTitle>(type: T, title: String) {
        T.objectWithTitle(title: title)
    }
}
```

Now, when I invoke the method like this:

```
SomeClass.dynamicMethod(type: Foo.self, title: "Title string!")
```

I get the following compiler error: `error: argument type 'Foo.Type' does not conform to expected type 'SettableTitle'
SomeClass.dynamicMethod(type: Foo.self, title: "Title string!")`

I can't understand why this would happen when the class `Foo` declares and implements `SettableTitle` conformance.

All this is in a simple playground in Xcode 8.3 (latest non-beta). Can anyone see anything I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is expecting an object that implements `SettableTitle`, not a type.

Instead, you need to do `T.Type`, and it will work:

```
class SomeClass {
  static func dynamicMethod<T: SettableTitle>(type: T.Type, title: String) {
    T.objectWithTitle(title: title)
  }
}
```

Source: [Using a Type Variable in a Generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905060/using-a-type-variable-in-a-generic)

Comment: This did the trick! I guess I should go re-read the chapter on Generics. Thanks!