# How does type(of: ) work in Swift for downcasting?

Tags: swift

How can I do this:

```
if let myVar = someValue as? type(of: myOtherVar) { ...
```

Compiler keeps on dying.

Comment: Not possible. "Swift's static typing means the type of a variable must be known at compile time.". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905060/using-a-type-variable-in-a-generic

Comment: That is super lame lol. Because you can have an array of AnyHashable, which the compiler DID know the type of everything that went INTO to array. So why now did it freaking forget what it already knew like 5 nanoseconds ago?! And how am I supposed to make sure something is a particular type before runtime if I cannot even `guard let` or `if let` to see what it is? Jeez.

Comment: I mean... I can make a `let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: someValue)` and `print(mirror.subtype)` to see the real type that the type eraser AnyHashable (or whatever) has hidden. Yet I cannot `guard let downcastedValue as? mirror.subtype`... wth

Comment: Well the compiler shouldn't just die, report that as a bug. As to your question, what are you trying to achieve? What do you intend to do with `myVar`?

Comment: @CRD I am trying to take type-erased PartialKeyPath<T> from an array and try to downcast them back into the non-type-erased form they had before they were put into the type-erased array.

Comment: But what can you do with the non-type-erased form? You don't at compile time know what actual type that is going to be (or else you would be casting to a constant type), which surely limits what you can do with it? Maybe editing your question showing what you intend to do with this `PartialKeyPath` will enable someone to explain how you can do, or why you cannot do, what you want.

Comment: What can you do with it? You can set the value of an object via `someThing[keyPath: myPath] = myValue`. But if the keyPath is a type-erased PartialKeyPath and the myValue is a type-erased Any, then even if the frickin’ myValue is really Int, and `myValue is Int` returns true, and same with the keypath (we can check yes, it’s int), even here in this case we cannot even do a simple assignment (not even in a safe `try` or `guard` manner) unless we explicitly cast to a concrete type! That defeats the whole point of generics...!!!

Comment: @CommaToast You're confusing the compiler with runtime. `type(of:)` is a dynamic function that reflects the value *at runtime*, not at compile time. Chances are you can achieve your end goal with generics, but since you only posted half a line of code we can't help you with that :)

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I will post more if I have time. It’s complicated. They really need a way to “force unwrap” a type-erased type back to its real type without telling the compiler necessarily what it will be. Just as long as it knows that it will be the same as the other type, and it can see from your code what range of types could go there, that should honestly be enough.

Comment: Chances are that type of functionality will eventually be added, but in my experience there are currently tools (if you're willing to get creative) to do almost everything in a type safe manor. One advantage of Swift is easily eliminating entire categories of crashes in a compiled language. Dynamic casting at runtime is expensive and error prone.

Comment: @CommaToast - At a *guess* your scenario might be closer to existential than generic types *per se*, and if so Swift's type system *may* not support your scenario, but unless you get past "It's complicated" and post more code people are unlikely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered just this working:

`if type(of:someValue) == type(of:myOtherVar) {...`

Maybe this will make your day:

```
func value<T,U>(_ a:T, inTypeOf b:U) -> U? {
    return a as? U
}

var x = 10 as Any
var y = 20

var z = value(x, inTypeOf: y)
```

Comment: It does work, but you still cannot make a new variable of that type!

Comment: I can. `if type(of:someValue) == type(of:myOtherVar), case let x = someValue {...`

Comment: Michael, that is fool’s gold. If one is type-erased or upcasted, like or `let x = 1337 as Any`, etc., your check succeed even though if you pass them into a generic function with two arguments and two type, then after that, the same check will fail! You will be forced to explicitly downcast before you can use a type-erased value for what it really is...!

Comment: I have edited my answer - now could meet your needs.

Comment: I will check it in the morning. But I am worried that if `y=“z” as Any` here, then z will be `10 as Any` just like x...