# Swift: Pass type from property to generic function

Tags: swift, generics, swift4, swift-protocols, codable

For my networking module, I have this protocol that I adopt for accessing different parts of the API:

```
protocol Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    var baseUrl: URL { get }        
    var route: Route { get }        
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }        
    var headers: [String: String]? { get }        
    var encoding: ParameterEncoding? { get }        
    var responseResultType: Decodable.Type? { get }
}
```

I'm adopting this with enums that look like this:

```
enum TestRouter: Router {
    case getTestData(byId: Int)
    case updateTestData(byId: Int)

    var route: Route {
        switch self {
        case .getTestData(let id): return Route(path: "/testData/\(id)")
        case .updateTestData(let id): return Route(path: "/testDataOtherPath/\(id)")
        }
    }

    var method: HTTPMethod {
        switch self {
        case .getTestData: return .get
        case .updateTestData: return .put
        }
    }

    var headers: [String : String]? {
        return [:]
    }

    var encoding: ParameterEncoding? {
        return URLEncoding.default
    }

    var responseResultType: Decodable.Type? {
        switch self {
        case .getTestData: return TestData.self
        case .updateTestData: return ValidationResponse.self
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use `Codable` for decoding nested Api responses. Every response consists of a token and a result which content is depending on the request route.

For making the request I want to use the type specified in the `responseResultType` property in the  `enum` above.

```
struct ApiResponse<Result: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let token: String
    let result: Result
}

extension Router {
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        // Construct URL
        var completeUrl = baseUrl.appendingPathComponent(route.path, isDirectory: false)
        completeUrl = URL(string: completeUrl.absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding ?? "")!
        // Create URL Request...
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: completeUrl)
        // ... with Method
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        // Add headers
        headers?.forEach { urlRequest.addValue($0.value, forHTTPHeaderField: $0.key) }
        // Encode URL Request with the parameters
        if encoding != nil {
            return try encoding!.encode(urlRequest, with: route.parameters)
        } else {
            return urlRequest
        }
    }

    func requestAndDecode(completion: @escaping (Result?) -> Void) {
        NetworkAdapter.sessionManager.request(urlRequest).validate().responseData { response in
            let responseObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResponse<self.responseResultType!>, from: response.data!)
            completion(responseObject.result)
        }
    }
}
```

But in my `requestAndDecode` method It throws an compiler error (`Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Any.Type, from: Data)'`). I can't use `ApiResponse<self.responseResultType!>` like that.

I could make this function generic and call it like this:

```
TestRouter.getTestData(byId: 123).requestAndDecode(TestData.self, completion:)
```

but then I'd have to pass the response type everytime I want to use this endpoint.

What I want to achieve is that the extension function `requestAndDecode` takes it response type information from itself, the `responseResultType` property.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the actual error report you have a fundamental problem with `requestAndDecode`: it is a generic function whose type parameters are determined at the call site which is declared to return a value of type `Result` yet it attempts to return a value of type `self.responseResultType` whose value is an *unknown* type.

If Swift's type system supported this it would require runtime type checking, potential *failure*, and your code would have to handle that. E.g. you could pass `TestData` to `requestAndDecode` while `responseResultType` might be `ValidationResponse`...

Change the JSON call to:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResponse<Result>.self ...
```

and the types statically match (even though the actual type that `Result` is is unknown).

You need to rethink your design. HTH

Comment: You're right, I mixed the two versions of the function (first with generics and the other one without). I updated the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understood why it's not possible. This question is similar and has also good explanations in it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905060/using-a-type-variable-in-a-generic)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Generic function with Combine and AlomFire. You can use it for all method(get, post, put, delete)

```
 func fatchData<T: Codable>(requestType: String, url: String, params: [String : Any]?, myType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {

    var method = HTTPMethod.get
    switch requestType {
    case "Get":
        method = HTTPMethod.get
    case "Post":
        method = HTTPMethod.post
        print("requestType  \(requestType) \(method) ")
    case "Put":
        method = HTTPMethod.put
    default:
        method = HTTPMethod.delete
    }

    print("url  \(url) \(method)  \(AppConstant.headers)  ")
    task =  AF.request(url, method: method, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: AppConstant.headers)
        .publishDecodable(type: myType.self)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
            switch completion{
            case .finished:
                ()
            case .failure(let error):
               // completion(.failure(error))
                print("error  \(error)")
            }
        }, receiveValue: {
            [weak self ](response) in
            
            print("response \(response)")

            switch response.result{
            
            case .success(let model):
                completion(.success(model))
                print("error success")

            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))

                print("error failure \(error.localizedDescription)")

            }
        }
    )
}
```